# I am getting stale data from .env file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables

I have a React Application. I am using the .env file for my environment files . and using dotenv-webpack module for parsing the .env file in React so that when I use process.env.XXXX in my code I can get the value as defined in the .env file. I see that when I change the value in .env file still the data when I read in React app is old data ..it is not reflecting the change I did in .env file.

in webpack.config.js ------

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv-webpack';

....
....
plugins:[
...
..
new dotenv()
]
```

in my .env file

```
GRAPHQL=http://localhost:3000
```

in my react js code I read this as

```
process.env.GRAPHQL
```

it should get the latest value as in .env file. But it shows some old value that I had earlier when I first put in the variable in the .env file

Comment: `GARAPHQL` is not `GRAPHQL`

Comment: If this is not a typo issue, after changing the value in the `.env` file, did you restart your server or no?

Comment: My apology it was a typo in the question . I have that updated .

Comment: I restarted the server post this change but do not see the desired output

Comment: If it doesn't work out for you, you can always try different packages. The package 'dotenv' worked properly for me..

Comment: My understanding is, as this is a browser side app so we need webpack else process.env will not work in ReactJs ..hence using dotenv-webpack. @natsuozawa

Comment: @CoolOS I see, thanks

Comment: If your project is generated with `create-react-app`, try preprending your custom env variables with `REACT_APP_` so `REACT_APP_GRAPHQL`, restart the server and access it with the prefix as well. Another possible reason is that you have multiple .env files and it's using the wrong one during build.

Comment: project was not created with create-react-app .and I am able to see the values ..it's that they are stale ..(i.e. not the latest in .env)  and i have only only 1 .env file as of now in the project